# Minecraft commands CanPlaceOn - Granite

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a problem. I'm trying to make a command to give a block that can only be placed on granite:

```
/give @p wool 1 6 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone[variant=2]"]}
```

However, this isn't working. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

`{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}` will allow you to place the block on all stone variants.

Unfortunately `CanPlaceOn` (and `CanDestroy`) do not support only specifying a specific data value of a block. [A bug report on it was marked as invalid.](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-55931)